# Submitting a web form in python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Please could someone convert the following from python2 to python3;

```
import requests

url = "http://duckduckgo.com/html"
payload = {'q':'python'}
r = requests.post(url, payload)
with open("requests_results.html", "w") as f:
f.write(r.content)
```

and I get;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\temp\Python\testFile.py", line 1, in <module>
import requests
ImportError: No module named 'requests'
```

I have also tried;

```
import urllib.request

url = "http://duckduckgo.com/html"
payload = {'q':'python'}
r = urllib.request.post(url, payload)
with open("requests_results.html", "w") as f:
f.write(r.content)
```

but I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\temp\Python\testFile.py", line 5, in <module>
r = urllib.request.post(url, payload)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'post'
```

Comment: What problems did you run into when you did that on Python 3?

Comment: this,
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\temp\Python\testFile.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
    ImportError: No module named 'requests'

Comment: Did you *install* `requests` for Python 3? It is not a standard library (in Python 2 *or* 3).

Comment: I have read that requests has been replaced with urllib.request, is this correct?

Comment: @scott no. `urllib.request` is what previously (py2) was `urllib` and `urllib2`. [`requests`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) is an external library.

Comment: Okay, thanks. As you can tell I am new to this. All I am trying to use python for is to submit a username and password to automatically login to a website. Is there a better way than I am trying to do it above?

Answer (score 0):

So, in python3.2, r.content is a bytestring, not a str, and write does not like it. You might want to use r.text instead:

```
with open("requests_results.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(r.text)
```

You can see it in the requests documentation in http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api.html#main-interface

> ```
> class requests.Response
>     content - Content of the response, in bytes.
>     text - Content of the response, in unicode. if Response.encoding is None and chardet     module is available,
> ```
>
> encoding will be guessed.

Edit:

I posted before seeing the edited question. Yeah, like  Martijn Pieters said, you need to install the requests module for python3 in order to be able to import it.

Comment: that's definitely not the problem here.

Comment: Yeah, the original question did not specify the actual error.

Comment: What is the easiest way to submit a web form in python3?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that there is no Requests package installed. Or if you have installed it's installed in your python2.x directory and not in python3 so which is why you're not able to use requests module. Try making python3 as your default copy and then install requests.

Also try visiting this[article](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml) by Michael Foord which walks you through using all the features of urlib2

Comment: And of course dont forget [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) for more info

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

url = "https://duckduckgo.com/html"
values = {'q':'python'}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values).encode("utf-8")

req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()

print(the_page)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value.